# Create a variable in Vertica

Tags: sql, ssms, vertica

I am transitioning from SQL Server to Vertica.  Is there any comparable way to create a variable?

Usually I do something like:

```
Define @myVariable int
Set @myVariable = select MAX(Field1) from myTable
```

Comment: Vertica is based on Postgres, so I would expect Postgres-style declarations to work (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Vertica is a column-oriented database, PostgerSQL is not. How can Vertica be "based" on Postgres?

Comment: @Mauro . . . The license for Postgres code permits developers to modify the code *and re-sell it*.  Many more recent databases are based on Postgres -- Greenplum, ParAccel, Netezza, Redshift, for example.  Actually, this isn't a big secret.  The Postgres Wiki proudly proclaims the many derivative databases:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_derived_databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff exactly! And this is what they say:"Column-oriented DataWarehouse (created by Stonebraker),
may only be forking the psql client library."

Answer (score 5):

I do not think Vertica allows variables, except if you are using vsql directly, but then vsql variables are very limited and will not do what you expect:

```
-- this will work
\set a foo
\echo :a
foo

-- this is not what you expect:
\set a NOW()
\echo :a
NOW()

\set a select max(id) from s.items()
\echo :a
selectmax(id)froms.items()
```

See for more information the vertica doc at  https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#2732.htm

Comment: I should clarify: I'm running my queries in DBeaver, so I can't use this trick.  Perhaps the issue is not one of Vertica necessarily?

Comment: It is Vertica itself which does not allow variables, except under a very limited form via vsql. Your other workaround are programming or subqueries.

Comment: you should put your query in apostrophes and braces if you want to use it in SQL later. E.g.: `\set a '(select max(id) from s.items())'`

Answer (score 2):

You do not "create variables" in Vertica the same way you do not "create variables" in SQL Server. What you're trying to convert is a T-SQL script.

You can do the same in Vertica by creating Perl or Python or Java ... scripts running *outside* the database or writing a user defined function in C++ or R or Java running *inside* Vertica.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:variable_name` in Vertica for a user input variable. For example:

```
select date_time from table_1 where date_time between :start and :end
```

In above `start` and `end` are the variables. When you run the query, a dialog box opens prompting you to enter the values for `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vsql, you can create variables that contain results of queries, though it is a bit convoluted:

Lets assume you start vsql with `vsql -v INARG=33`;

```
SELECT :INARG+1;                -- Set up the query
\pset format u
\pset t                         -- Update output format to bare
\g `echo /tmp/dyneval`          -- Eval the query and write into file
\set DYNARG `cat /tmp/dyneval`  -- Set var from shell command output
\echo :DYNARG
```

So basically we write the query result into a file and read the file's contents into a variable.

You can use `/tmp/dyneval-${PPID}_id` instead of `/tmp/dyneval`, so you can ensure, that parallel executions wont alter each other. (PPID being the parent process's process ID, that is the vsql process's PID.)

The solution has some limitations:

- assumes a linux env (echo, cat)
- it changes the output formatting settings (\pset)